# Creating custom amazon webstore design

Tags: layout, webstore

I am trying to create an amazon webstore and the interface is just appalling.

I have seen a few companies that have made really decent stores but have no idea how they have accomplished this using the interface amazon give you as they make it near on impossible to customise a single thing.

Could someone please shed a light on what it is I need to do to create a fully customised design for my store?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had luck in creating a custom layout... functionality is where I'm stuck.  It seems we are FORCED to use their widgets, etc... though you can change the look of them quite easily.

I made my way by using Google Chrome's inspect element tool (F12).  I was able to find the CSS that drives the different widgets for width, height, etc.  Also, I was able to write my own CSS for, say, the search widget.

Your question is about 1.5 months old... so I assume you may have learned your way by now.

If you have any questions, I'd be happy to assist with what I know.

Comment: I used firebug but I'm glad I've found someone who agrees with me. It's terrible but I worked my way through it. Thanks for commenting. :)